# Related if in one of two fields in Django

Tags: python, django

I have two m2m related fields in my model `admins` and `users`. 
I want to add constraint that single `Profile` can be connected only to one of `admins` or `users` field.

What is the best way to implement it in django?

```py
class Session(models.Model):
    admins = models.ManyToManyField(Profile, related_name='admins')
    users = models.ManyToManyField(Profile, related_name='users')
```

Comment: What is the best way to resolve it?  What is the best way to resolve what?  What error(s) are you getting?

Comment: Please re-read your question and correct it: "but specified Profile can but in of admins or users in one Session" does not make any sense in English.

Comment: Sorry guys I have reformated description a little bit. I hope it's clear now.